# In MS SQL Server mgt studio, is there a way to format select results like mysql \G

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I would like to have the results of my query (that returns one row) to be displayed in text like this:

```
columnA: value
columnB: value
columnC: value
```

as happens in mysql when using

```
select * from tablename \G
```

Is there a way to do this? The reason for this is that it is helpful to be able to print out one record with columns and values for example data or to share a record from a table that has many columns and which would be hard to view across the screen.

Comment: so you just want to pivot the data?

Comment: I guess one way to do this would be to copy the results, paste into Excel, and then copy/paste transpose

Comment: you can pivot in sql server

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite so simple as your MySQL example, but you can do an unpivot to get what you want.

```
---------------
-- TEST SCHEMA
---------------
declare @tablename as Table(keyvalue varchar(2), dataColA varchar(2), dataColB varchar(2), dataColC varchar(2))
insert into @tablename select '01', '02', '03', '04'

---------------
-- UNPIVOT
---------------
select dataColumns, dataValues
from @tablename
unpivot
(
  dataValues
  for dataColumns in (keyvalue, dataColA, dataColB, dataColC)
) u;
```

Comment: Sorry for my lack of familiarity but do I have to code the names of the columns every time? Typically, when I need to do this, I am looking at a table with 50-100 columns and I'm unfamiliar with the schema (I do a lot of "data discovery" troubleshooting reports generated from a data repository with thousands of tables.) I suppose I could generate the column names from information_schema but I was hoping there was a formatting way to do this.

Comment: yes you need the column names to unpivot.  You can drag them over from the object browser though to save some time.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish what I want is to

1. execute the query to a results grid, limit to top 1 if necessary to ensure only one row is returned,
2. right-click in top left corner, Copy with Headers
3. open Excel, paste
4. select what was just pasted and copy again within Excel
5. go to blank area of workbook or new worksheet and Paste Special, Transpose

This will create one row per database query column with column name in column A and value in column B.